# Difference between Google fusion table IDs

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Why does some fusion tables have a integer ID, ex:

```
var tableid =  3186367;
```

and others have a string ID like the following:

```
var tableid = '1VlPiBCkYt_Vio-JT3UwM-U__APurJvPb6ZEJPg'
```

What's the difference between both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numeric ids are the old deprecated way of referencing the tables.  The string id is the newer way.  Numeric ids don't work in some cases.